# Facebook like button not showing when using a dynamic app id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm building a website for a franchise organization that has many franchisees. Each franchisee claims it's own part of the site represented within the path - for example the main site url is bigcompany.com and the the Atlanta store url will be bigcompany.com/atlanta. When trying to place the like button on the page it works when given the main organization's app id, but shows nothing when given the franchise app id.

I've tried using the url debugger on facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and the error that I receive is

```
Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://bigcompany.com/atlanta' of `type 'website' is invalid because the given value '12345678901' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.`
```

I'm not sure what that means and haven't found a suitable answer so far.

Why is the like button not showing? Thanks

Comment: Have you hard-coded a user ID somewhere?

Comment: I haven't hard-coded a user ID.